# TEA Encryption, Assembly implementation

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, cryptography, nasm

As I'm trying to improve my x86 Assembly skill, I'm developing the NASM implementation of the [Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm).

Encryption algorithm is defined as follows:

```
void encrypt (uint32_t v[2], uint32_t k[4]) {
    uint32_t v0=v[0], v1=v[1], sum=0, i;           /* set up */
    uint32_t delta=0x9E3779B9;                     /* a key schedule constant */
    uint32_t k0=k[0], k1=k[1], k2=k[2], k3=k[3];   /* cache key */
    for (i=0; i<32; i++) {                         /* basic cycle start */
        sum += delta;
        v0 += ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1);
        v1 += ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3);
    }                                              /* end cycle */
    v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;
}
```

Unfortunately my NASM version seems to be broken somewhere and, until now, I wasn't able to find the error(s).

NASM implementation was developed under *nix x86 and should be linked with the following command as I'm directly writing in the .text section at runtime: `ld -m elf_i386 -N -o tea tea.nasm`

Here my code so far:

```
global _start
; EAX = store arithmetic results
; ECX = COUNTER
; EBX = current chunk (v0,v1)
; EDX = sum
; ESI = *encrypted_shellcode
; EDI = *key
section .text
_start:
    jmp short key_section               ; goto key_section

key_section:
    ; key0: 0x6c645a37
    ; key1: 0x6e775667
    ; key2: 0x57433641
    ; key3: 0x4e6c7151
    call key_loader                 ; goto key_loader, putting key on the stack
    ;       |          0          |            1           |           2          |            3           |
    ;       |         EDI         |          EDI+4         |         EDI+8        |          EDI+12        |
    key: db 0x6c, 0x64, 0x5a, 0x37, 0x6e, 0x77, 0x56, 0x67, 0x57, 0x43, 0x36, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x6c, 0x71, 0x51

key_loader:
    pop edi                             ; load address of our key into EDI (JMP CALL POP trick)
    jmp short shellcode_section         ; goto shellcode_section

encoder:                                ; encoder
    pop esi                             ; load address of our shellcode into ESI (JMP CALL POP trick)
    mov ecx, 3                          ; load the number of our shellcode chunks, used to loop. (shellcode length is 24. 24/4(DWORD)=6 blocks/2(chunks taken 2by 2)=3)
    ;cld                                ; clear direction flag, setting it to 0. 

encrypt_loop:
    push ecx                            ; save counter status before entering 32 iteration loop
    mov ecx, 32                         ; store loop counter, we nedd to cycle x32 times
    xor edx, edx                        ; clean EDX (sum), EDX = 0
    loop_32:
        mov ebx, dword [esi+4]          ; v1 load encrypted_shellcode's chunk DWORD pointed by ESI in EBX | EBX=B
        ; sum = sum+delta
        add edx, 0x9E3779B9             ; sum = sum+delta
        ; v0 = v0 + ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1);
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v1 is now in EAX
        shl eax, 4                      ; v1<<4
        add eax, dword [edi]            ; +k0
        push eax                        ; store EAX (result) on stack
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v1 is now in EAX
        add eax, edx                    ; v1 + sum
        push eax                        ; store EAX (result) on stack
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v1 is now in EAX
        shr eax, 5                      ; v1>>5
        add eax, dword [edi+4]          ; +k1
        ; EAX = ((v1>>5) + k1)
        pop ebx                         ; restore EBX = (v1 + sum)
        xor eax, ebx                    ; EAX = (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1)
        pop ebx                         ; restore EBX = (v1<<4) + k0)
        xor eax, ebx                    ; EAX = ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1)
        add eax, dword [esi]            ; v0 = v0 + ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1)
        mov dword [esi], eax            ; store encrypted v0 back to shellcode "buffer"
        ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mov ebx, dword [esi]            ; v0 load shellcode's chunk DWORD pointed by ESI in EBX | EBX=A
        ; v1 = v1 + ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3);
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v0 is now in EAX
        shl eax, 4                      ; v0<<4
        add eax, dword [edi+8]          ; +k2
        push eax                        ; store EAX (result) on stack
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v0 is now in EAX
        add eax, edx                    ; v0 + sum
        push eax                        ; store EAX (result) on stack
        mov eax, ebx                    ; v0 is now in EAX
        shr eax, 5                      ; v0>>5
        add eax, dword [edi+12]         ; +k3
        ; EAX = ((v0>>5) + k3)
        pop ebx                         ; restore EBX = (v0 + sum)
        xor eax, ebx                    ; EAX = (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3)
        pop ebx                         ; restore EBX = (v0<<4) + k2)
        xor eax, ebx                    ; EAX = ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3)
        add eax, dword [esi+4]          ; v1 = v1 + ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3)
        mov dword [esi+4], eax          ; store encrypted v1 back to shellcode "buffer"
        loop loop_32                    ; ECX is 0? No, we go back at loop_32 and execute the cicle again
    pop ecx                             ; restore ECX counter status
    add esi, 8                          ; select next chunk "couple"                
    loop encrypt_loop                   ; ECX is 0? No, we go back at decrypt_loop and execute the cicle again
    exec:
    int3                                ; ECX is 0! We've encrypted our shellcode. GDB: x/24cb encrypted_shellcode

shellcode_section:
        call encoder                    ; goto decoder, putting shellcode on the stack
        ;                       |          A          |           B           |           C           |           D            |          E           |            F          |
        ;                       |         ESI         |         ESI+4         |         ESI+8         |         ESI+12         |        ESI+16        |          ESI+20       |
        encrypted_shellcode: db 0x31, 0xc0, 0x50, 0x68, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x68, 0x2f, 0x62, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x87, 0xe3, 0xb0, 0x0b, 0xcd, 0x80, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90
        ;                       |<-chunk read direction|
```

C implementation works correctly (it is able to encrypt/decrypt) and return the following:

- Original v0 0x31c05068
- Original v1 0x2f2f7368
- k0=0x6c645a37, k1=0x6e775667, k2=0x57433641, k3=0x4e6c7151

C:

- Crypted v0: 0x17c59b4a
- Crypted v1: 0xf8c4497

ASM:

- Crypted v0: 0x56efe51
- Crypted v1: 0xba4731e3

Why my implementation does not works? What am I missing?

Thank you all in advance and please be kind as I'm not an expert

Comment: ok, one of the error could be related to the endianness of the values but I'm still checking it

Comment: Have you tried using GDB or any other debugger to single-step through your C and asm code, and see where your asm register values stop matching C variable values?  While this is a [mcve] with actual vs. desired outputs, the whole point of an encryption algo is to make it hard to work backwards from outputs to inputs.  Interactive debugging is probably your best bet for narrowing down the part that's wrong.

Comment: Oh and BTW, yes, `db 0x31, 0xc0, 0x50, 0x68` is *big* endian `0x31c05068`.  Use `dd 0x31c05068` to get NASM to store your uint32_t in x86 native little-endian byte order.  You would have seen this right away in the result of the `mov ebx, dword [esi+4]` load or simply just using GDB to examine memory, if you'd used a debugger.

Comment: Also note: `call key_loader` jumps forward, so its rel32 displacement will contain `00` bytes.  There is no `call short` with a rel8.  So you're defeating the purpose of this shellcode trick and just making things more complicated than necessary; use `mov reg, label` to put a label address into a register.  (Unless you only want to learn stuff that works in shellcode, not "normal" asm like a compiler would make.)

Comment: I'm using GDB going step by step, that's why I got the endianness :)
But yes, your comments makes sense, I should have relayed more on GDB.

I've definitely have to fix the endianness and it should work

Comment: BTW, it's not normal to use push/pop in the middle of a loop; just use more registers (For example, EBP is unused) or use `mov` to store to the stack so you can easily reload by using `[esp + 4]` or whatever as a memory source operand.  Or keep some infrequently-used (or at least infrequently-modified) thing in memory, like maybe the outer loop counter.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at how GCC and clang optimize your C for 32-bit x86: https://godbolt.org/z/ZydsmK.  (GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` is slightly different from NASM, e.g. dword ptr instead of dword, but for this code very much readable).  Note GCC's clever trick of `cmp  ebx, 0xC6EF3720` / `jne` as the loop condition, using the final `sum` value instead of a separate register for `i`.  (I assume it did constant propagation through those 32 iterations of += delta.)

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for all this information and tips. I will sure try to better understand GCC optimization and to write a more optimized code. You are always helpful :)